# User not showing on People page although listed when using Powershell

Tags: powershell, security, groups

I'm using SharePoint 2010 (14.0.4763.1000) and have a user that is not showing on the People page (_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=3). MembershipGroupId=3 is the Owner's Group.

When using PowerShell:

```
$group = $web.SiteGroups["XXXX Owner's Group"]
$group.Users
// Result : User listing and the user i'm looking for is listed
```

When doing $web.EnsureUser("_userlogin"), everything is working fine, but no change at all.

I can delete the User via PowerShell and add it back via the interface but it just won't show on the page.

Comment: Are your user and your farm in the same domain? Of not, which trusts are implemented between them?

Answer (score 2):

By default this page only shows 30 users and there is no paging available. Is it possible that this user is beyond the 30th user on the list? Most likely you don't have over 30 users in the owner's group, but I guess it's possible.

If so, as long as you have permissions on the User Information List, then from the people.aspx page click Settings > List Settings > List View (under Views) > Item Limit > change to something larger like 100.